# Rotating orbitals and parameters for a many-body calculation

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I am confused with some results I am getting. Given a molecule (In particular, I was toying with triangulenes, some benzenoids and things like that, but this is not very important), I perform first a tight-binding, Hartree-Fock or a DFT calculation to get some molecular orbitals $\phi_j$. Let me use greek indices $\mu$ to denote the sites on the lattice defining the molecule and latin indices to denote to molecular orbitals. I want to consider the Hubbard Model on the lattice
$$\hat{H}=-t \sum_{\langle \mu, \nu \rangle \sigma} \hat{c}^\dagger_{\mu \sigma}\hat{c}_{\nu \sigma} + \text{h.c.} + \frac{U}{2}\sum_{\mu \sigma} \hat{n}_{\mu \sigma}\hat{n}_{\mu \overline{\sigma}}.$$

I will solve exactly this model in an active space of a few  molecular orbitals around the Fermi level. Let's say I have the orbitals $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3,\phi_4$ in my active space (for example, $\phi_2$ may be the HOMO, $\phi_3$ the LUMO, and the others are the HOMO-1 and LUMO+1). I can easily find a many-body hamiltonian for these four orbitals from the Hubbard hamiltonian using the truncation:
$$\hat{c}_{\mu \sigma}  \approx \sum_j \phi_j(\mu) \hat{C}_{j \sigma},$$
where the $\hat{C}_{j \sigma}$ are the anihilation operators for the molecular orbitals.
Now, the many-body model can be exactly diagonalized for small active spaces.
However, in many cases of interest, some of the molecular orbitals used in the active space are degenerated, so actually the representation of the subspace can be chosen in many ways. This shouldn't change anything but, actually, by rotating the degenerate orbitals I change the parameters of the many-body hamiltonian and not only the absolute energies, but also the excitation energies depend on the chosen rotations.

What is behind this confusion?  Can it be fixed somehow?

So far, the only thing that I came up with was trying to find the energy minimum in the space of all possible representations (i.e., rotations) of the degenerate orbitals, but this is in general a very heavy computation, and I am not sure it makes sense anyway.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may want to ask this in https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okey, thanks for the tip, Maiti. Should I wait? Should I close this question before opening it on other site?

Comment: Yes, definitely you should wait for a couple of days, there are some computational chemistry people here too. If there is no response, then you should ask a question on matter modelling. What to do with the one here is a tough question, as cross-posting is usually discouraged. Personally, I would say leave both questions open, but give a link of the other to each question to tell people that you have cross-posted. I am not a moderator however. And good luck with your question, it's quite interesting, but I don't know enough to answer.

Comment: @SRMaiti this question didn't end up getting any attention here, which was unfortunate for the OP since this was almost 6 months ago. In the future, perhaps I would be less hesitant to encourage migration earlier rather than later. In this case, the "couple days" wait didn't seem to do any good. Now a migration won't be possible due to the 60-day limit for migrations, so Qwertuy will have to post on MMSE manually.